# Save webpage to server folder

Tags: php, curl, save, directory

Is there any way to save a external web page to folder on server but with all webpage elements (JS files,images,css... etc.). Like you can do at browser with option save-complete-page but I need this to save with php on my server folder. And when include this folder to show the page as original. Maybe with curl or some php function ... ???

HOW TO DO THAT. please HELP!

p.s.I doing this for good reason not for stealing content!

and when I finising with operation and function I will empty the folder.

Comment: wget is designed to crawl and download all components in a web page. http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/

Comment: but how to implement wget, plase show me an example, how to integrate with same php

Comment: The fastest solution is use PHP to `exec(wget...);`. I don't think there is PHP extension for this (I might be wrong)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curl or file\_get\_contents for downloading whole webpage with css, images and JS files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508723/curl-or-file-get-contents-for-downloading-whole-webpage-with-css-images-and-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to visit a php site as a client (whether in a browser or via wget/curl/etc) and then save all related server-side files?

**Without access to the server, that is not possible**. The server-side content (e.g. the PHP pages and possibly some other parts of the site) are [interpretted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) by the server before you as a client see any part of the site. You need server-side access to the files in order to see what is there before the code is interpretted.

Comment: I need only example source code of some page HTML (file_get_contents) and other inculded files like /file/script.js /file/css.css images and similar... not acces to any php files

Comment: example: get source code HTML with file_get-content and save to my folder like html page

Comment: and get other files and save too