# wget combined with php

Tags: php, wget

Is there some way to type a URL in a text field, click submit on my page and use PHP to download all content from that URL with wget, saving the files to a folder on my server?

Comment: Yes, it's called [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). But don't. Use [cURL](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or simply [`file_get_contents()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead.

Comment: Download all content means images, styles, scripts and so on? I believe wget can do it but PHP is the least of your worries then.

Comment: unless this is a "local" only thing, then whats to stop someone downloading a copy of c99shell and executing it on your server

Comment: is there any php function like file_get_content or with curl that download source code and other inculded files (css,js,images)

Comment: How to add folder location for storing files with that: <?php
 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        exec('wget ' . $_POST['name']);
}
?>
 
<form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="url" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download" />
</form>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save webpage to server folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507099/save-webpage-to-server-folder)

Comment: Have you considered reading the manual on either?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curl or file\_get\_contents for downloading whole webpage with css, images and JS files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508723/curl-or-file-get-contents-for-downloading-whole-webpage-with-css-images-and-js)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can use PHP [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec) function (or similar) to execute external commands (such as `wget`).

If you need all site assets then I'd use the options for `wget`. Otherwise, if you just need the page content, I'd do it natively with PHP as suggested in the comment from **DaveRandom**.

**Note:** Use at your own risk... The scenario you describe is dripping with evil.

Comment: Something like [http://pastebin.com/AqkUn6XC](http://pastebin.com/AqkUn6XC) will work but as Jason says its very dangerous without sanitizing for example someone could put something like ; rm -rf / in the text field then buy buy files

Comment: No, I dont want to hack any web site or something becouse I will empty the folder after I do some operations in javascript

Comment: No, just me will using that and I will not put this rm

Comment: It's not what *you* will use it for, it's what *others* will use it for. It it's on the web it can be used wrongly.

Comment: how to add folder location for storing that: <?php
 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        exec('wget ' . $_POST['name']);
}
?>
 
<form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="url" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download" />
</form>