# Curl or file_get_contents for downloading whole webpage with css, images and JS files

Tags: php, curl, save, directory, file-get-contents

What I'm need is to get source code of some webpage URL:

```
$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

after that string I need to save as HTML file in my server folder and after that I need to save other elements od pages (images,css and JS files) and also put on server folder...

After that all, I need to show this page as on my domain to looks like iframe but with source code which I need for other actions.

HOW TO DO THAT! with php file_get_contents or with some cUrl functions or ... suggest you!

Comment: More or less an exact duplicate of [this current question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508279/wget-combined-with-php), which is itself a dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507099/save-webpage-to-server-folder) which is a dupe of many, many others.

Comment: No i't not duplicate, it's my code!!!

Comment: Based on this sentence `HOW TO DO THAT!`, they are the same user with two (or more) accounts

Comment: this is my only account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse all web site urls, src= href= etc etc etc. it's really hard to do that. Try out hidemyass.com , and look that not any web site will work correctly because of js. The script you are looking for is called WebProxy.